# Avoid creating temporary scalars when returning multiple arrays

Tags: raku

Is it possible to avoid creating temporary scalars when returning multiple arrays from a function:

```
use v6;
sub func() {
    my @a = 1..3;
    my @b = 5..10;
    return @a, @b;
}
my ($x, $y) = func();
my @x := $x;  
my @y := $y;
say "x: ", @x;  # OUTPUT: x: [1 2 3]
say "y: ", @y;  # OUTPUT: y: [5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

I would like to avoid creating the temporary variables `$x` and `$y`. 
Note: It is not possible to replace the function call with

```
my (@x, @y) = func()
```

since [assignment of a list to an `Array` is eager](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Assigning) and therefore both the returned arrays end up in `@x`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not either of:

```
my ($x, $y) = func();
my (@x, @y) = func();
```

But instead either of:

```
my (@x, @y) := func();
my ($x, $y) := func();
```

Use `@` to signal to P6 that, when it needs to distinguish whether something is singular -- "a single array" -- or plural -- "items contained in a single array" -- it should be treated as plural.

Use `$` to signal the other way around -- it should be treated as singular.

You can always later explicitly reverse this by doing `$@x` -- to signal P6 should use the singular perspective for something you originally declared as plural -- or `@$x` to signal reversing the other way around.

For an analogy, think of a cake cut into several pieces. Is it a single thing or a bunch of pieces? Note also that `@` caches indexing of the pieces whereas `$` just remembers that it's a cake. For large lists of things this can make a big difference.